# Is there any way to speed up my download of Laravel homestead via vagrant?

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I have installed Vagrant and Virtualbox on my Windows 10 machine. I'm now running the line below on my command prompt

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead --box-version 8.1.0
```

I did not expect the download to be painfully slow. The line has been runing for about 4 hours and I'm still nowhere near 50%. The download is redirected to the host vagrantcloud-files-production.s3.amazon.com

Is there any command line that will let me install Laravel Homestead in a much faster time?